# Android OpenGL ES 1.1 Sphere texture mapping problem

Tags: android, opengl-es, geometry

I have a terrible issues with texure sphere mapping.

This is my code:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl10, EGLConfig config) {  

  GL11 gl = (GL11) gl10;
  gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);    //Disable Depth Testing
  gl.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  gl.glEnable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE);
  gl.glCullFace(GL11.GL_FRONT);
  gl.glFrontFace(GL11.GL_CCW);
  sphere.loadGLTexture(gl10, context);
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl10) {

  GL11ExtensionPack gl= (GL11ExtensionPack) gl10;

  gl10.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
  gl10.glLoadIdentity();
  gl10.glFrustumf(-5.0f, 5.0f, -5.0f, 5.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f); //Mio 
  gl10.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
  gl10.glLoadIdentity();
  GLU.gluLookAt(gl10, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,0.0f);
  sphere.draw(gl10);
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width_, int height_) {
  gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height); 


 }

public void draw(GL10 gl10) {

  GL11ExtensionPack gl = (GL11ExtensionPack) gl10;
  GL11 gl11 = (GL11) gl10;
  gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures_ids.get(0));
  gl10.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, totalVertexCount);
}

public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl10, Context context) {

  GL11 gl = (GL11) gl10;
  gl.glGenTextures(2, textures_ids);
  gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures_ids.get(0));
  gl.glTexParameteri(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
  gl.glTexParameteri(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
  gl.glTexParameterf( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
  gl.glTexParameterf( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
  GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, this.image, 0);

  gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
  gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
  gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0,textureBuffer); 

 }
```

The vertexbuffer contains a points for a sphere and the texturebuffer contains the normals for that, I meet an horrible result and I don't understand what's wrong...

This is the result img:

http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/6370/failfs.png

I am working with android OpenGL ES but I think error isn't correlated with my platform but is correlated with my use of OpenGL API, I am a newbye with this library.

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong, You have to calc the normal for each point drawed.

Comment: Solved, there was some stupid issues.